# N'...' makes text unicode, but are the surrounding quotes unicode too?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unicode

My question is more about the specific parsing SQL Server would use.

I know prefixing a string with `N` tells SQL Server the text is Unicode. I guess my first question would be if SQL Server is parsing *all* text as Unicode (like in the SQL file or if a statement is being sent to it via another program)?

If not, if SQL Server is parsing text as ASCII/ANSI, then the title of this question comes into play. After processing the `N` character and realizing the text is Unicode, does it also expect the surrounding single-quotes to be Unicode or does it understand them to be ASCII/ANSI and only the things *inside* them to be Unicode?

Comment: which "surrounding quotes unicode too?" quote you are talking about ?

Comment: Interesting question, but what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For (somewhat funsies) I'm making a parameterized stored procedure invoker in code (C++, not that that's that important) and when someone passes in a wstring (collection of wchars, two bytes big each on Windows) I need to pass that in as well. That part's easy; store both bytes as part of the underlying string. But whether to also store the surrounding single tick characters as two bytes or not is my question